# Flutter continue for loop process till value exist

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array like this.

```
relatives = [
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'relation': 'GrandFather',
        'subrelatives': [
            {
                'name': 'julia',
                'relation': 'Daughter',  
                'subrelatives': [
                    {
                        'name': 'julia',
                        'relation': 'Daughter',  
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'alia',
                        'relation': 'Daughter',  
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'alia',
                'relation': 'Daughter',  
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

What I need to do is continue the for loop if sub relatives exist and add the value in array.

Right now for first sub relatives I am doing like this

```
for (var i = 1; i < res_data['data']['relatives'].length; i++) {
  print(i);
  nodes.add(gp.Node.Id(i));
  for (var j = 1; j < res_data['data']['relatives']['subrelatives'][i].length; j++) {
    nodes.add(gp.Node.Id(i + j));
  }
}
```

But this will work on first sub relatives and it continues array some time its in hundred. What I need to do is if subrelatives have subrelatives then it will continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to learn about [recursion algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/).

this is my data.

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "title": "Item 1",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Item 1.1",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "title": "Item 1.1.1",
                        "items": []
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Item 1.1.2",
                        "items": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Item 1.2",
                "items": []
            },
            {
                "title": "Item 1.3",
                "items": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Item 2",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Item 2.1",
                "items": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Item 3",
        "items": []
    }
]
}
```

this is my function for recursion.

```
void traverseTree(
  String parantId, Map<String, dynamic> itemdata, int i) {
final int lvl = i;

maxLvl = i + 1;
if (itemdata['items'] == []) {
  return;
}
for (var item in itemdata['items']) {
  item['parantId'] = parantId;
  item['level'] = lvl;
  item['exp'] = false;
  // print("lvl $lvl = parant = ${item['parantId']}    ${item['title']}");
  traverseTree(item['title'], item, lvl + 1);
   }
  }
```